# SimpleCursorAdapter within a ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I'm having  abit of an issue and i'm not too sure how to go about solving it.

Essentially i have an activity which has a base xml layout of ScrollView and i want this activity to list some results from a Cursor. So i thought i'd use SimpleCursorAdapter... however when i got it all set up it appears that the ListView that the SimpleCursorAdapter goes into doesn't play nice being within another scrollable layout element.

I've sorta got it working programmically but i'd much rather use a ListAdapter as it will make each list entry look like a button and keep it inline with the design of the rest of the application and can handle the ids of each item and where to send the user upon clicking.

So my question is this: is there anyway to either make ListView show all the items such that it never needs to scroll, or can i change the ListView to something like a LinearLayout?

I hope that makes sense!
Any help / insight / ideas are welcome!
Cheers!

Comment: So based on what i've coded and a few of the comments below, it's clear that a SimpleCursorAdapter isn't the way to go. What would be the best possible solution to achieve the list i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **NEVER** use a scroll view and a ListView together. Its a mess! and illogical as well.

Here are some of the approaches you can use:

1. Theres no screen big enough to show all the content of you listView you can try wrapping up your content but as I said it won't help as scroll view and list view don't work together. So you can either remove your or
2. If your list items are simple you can dynamically add your views to LinearLayout with specified location

Another tip I can give you is you can always use an relative layout and place your listView `alignParentBottom="true"` and emit the scrollView approach this will make you listview alwyas scrollable.

Comment: I do have some code that add's TextViews to a LinearLayout and that works ok, just was hoping to keep the UI more unified.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really make sense to have a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` at all. The `ListView` implements it's own scroll function so it should not be used in conjunction with a `ScrollView` anyway.

You should rethink your UI design.

Comment: So what would be the best way to implement what i want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Shardul; trying to put a listview with a scrollview will make it impossible to scroll. Have a look at the links below to see what you can accomplish with just a ListView -
a.

[custom backgrounds info](http://www.androidguys.com/tag/android-listview/).
[custom adapters](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html)